# Pagination for custom query throws 404 errors on last pages

Tags: wp-query, pagination, author-template

I'm using a custom query to get all CPT posts for the author in `author.php`. I have a lot of authors and a lot of content so I'm using the wp pagenavi plugin to paginate between these posts.

For some reason the pagination is giving me 404 errors on a lot of these pages. The pages that throw 404s is always the last or the two last pages of the pagination.

So for example `/author/steve/page/8/` will work, while `/author/steve/page/9/` and `/author/steve/page/10/` will not.

I believe the pagenavi plugin handles `'paged' => $paged`, but i've also tried setting $paged in the file: `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`, but with no difference.

My global post_per_page (in the dashboard setting) is 6 posts per page.
Changing `'posts_per_page' => 4` in the query to `'posts_per_page' => 6`, fixes the 404 issue, but is more of a dirty fix as I need to only display 4 posts per page.

Below is my query:

```
<?php
$author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );

if ( have_posts() ) : 

the_post();
rewind_posts();

$author_details = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query(array(
  'post_type'=> 'publikasjoner',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'meta_key' => 'rapportnummer',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'DSC',
  'author_name' => $curauth->user_nicename
));

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

// Post content

<?php endwhile; endif;

if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) ); }

$wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>
```

Comment: This question relates to the use of the wp-pagenavi plugin and therefore is better asked on that plugins forums. https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-pagenavi

Comment: 404s on archive pages are determined by the main query, modify that and don't use a custom query.

Comment: @BradDalton This has nothing to do with the pagination plugin. Please see the post I marked that this one is a duplicate to. That is the cause of this issue :-)

Comment: Depends which way you look at it. He wants to use wp-pagenavi as well.

Comment: @BradDalton it doesn't matter, even if you use core pagination functions, a plugin or your own custom function, it will never work. The main query will always 404 if you have more pages in a custom query than the main query and you go to a page that does not exists in the main query but does in the custom query

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what @Pieter Goosen said. Not only are you creating havoc for WordPress, you're adding unnecessary load on the server by introducing more queries *on top of* the main query:

```
function wpse_176933_custom_authors_archive( $wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_author() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'posts_per_page', 4 );
        $wp_query->set( 'post_type', 'publikasjoner' );
        $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'rapportnummer' );
        $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $wp_query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_176933_custom_authors_archive' );
```

Add this hook to your `functions.php`, remove any custom queries from `author.php`, and replace your custom loop with the main loop functions (`the_loop()`, `the_post()` etc.).